# Send emails with display name for toAddresses

Tags: apex, email

I am using this code snippet in an `Apex Class`, for sending mails:

```
Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email } );
```

Is this possible to show the display name of the receiver (on `toAddresses` field) on the received mail?

Current result on received mail:

> to:   "firstName.lastName@gmail.com" < firstName.lastName@gmail.com>

Desired Result:

> to: "firstName LastName" < firstName.lastName@gmail.com>

Comment: I guess it will be displayed first name and last name if to address added as contact in email

Comment: @Ratan I enter an email address of contact as a string on "SingleEmailMessage.setToAddresses". How can I add the address as contact?

Comment: no if your to address is testTo@gmail.com and your from address is testfrom@gmail.com then open testTo@gmail.com gmail and add contact as testfrom@gmail.com and give any name. Try this once hope this work

Comment: I am looking for a programmatic global solution, so it will apply to all users without making changes on gmail. For the sender field, for example, we can use SingleEmailMessage.setSenderDisplayName method for showing the display name of the sender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is not available, either on the `Messaging.Email` class ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_base.htm%23apex_classes_email_outbound_base)) or the `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` class ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm%23apex_classes_outbound_single)). <s>However, The `setTargetObjectId` method does seem to set it by default as `FirstName LastName` when sent to either a `User` or a `Contact`.</s>

**You have no control over the recipient display name in `Apex`.**

Comment: In your example, if you click on the arrow button, do you see your name on the list of the "to" addressees? Also, in my case, there can be more than one addressee, so I don't think that setTargetObjectId is suitable for me

Comment: As for the display name...I actually was mistaken, and that was still the sender display name.